# How to use cypress-image-snapshot without generating a new screenshot every test?

Tags: angular, cypress

I want to test the responsiveness of my website in Cypress by

- Making a screenshot of the page in a narrow viewport
- Scrolling programmatically to the right
- Test whether the page still matches the screenshot
  The idea is that, if my responsive layout works, it is not possible to scroll to the right: all the elements should still be visible.

I use the following code (only relevant code):

```
When('the page is displayed on a mobile viewport', () => {
    cy.viewport(800, 750);
    cy.screenshot();
});

Then('the page should not be scrollable in a horizontal direction', () => {
    cy.window().scrollTo('right');
    cy.matchImageSnapshot();
})
```

And

```
Feature: Grid

  I want to display containers in a responsive grid.

  Scenario: Displaying the page on a small viewport
    Given I visit the URL '/grid-page'
    When the page is displayed on a mobile viewport
    Then the page should not be scrollable in a horizontal direction
```

The screenshot is created and saved to `cypress/screenshots/grid.feature/Grid -- Displaying the page on a small viewport.png`.

However, each time I run the test it generates a new, duplicate snapshot (e.g. `cypress/screenshots/grid.feature/Grid -- Displaying the page on a small viewport(1).png`. How do I make sure that it just uses the existing screenshot (or overwrites it with the same name), instead of creating new numbered screenshots?

I already tried using `cy.screenshot('grid', {overwrite: 'true'});` and in commands.js, `addMatchImageSnapshotCommand({ overwrite: true });`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have configuration `trashAssetsBeforeRuns` set `false`? The default is `true`, but if it were so, the previous screenshot would be removed on start of nect test.

Ref [configuration - screenshots](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Screenshots)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it unfortunately. No settings other than default!